# How to search across the entire array of objects by passing in field set: javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I search across array of objects when I want to search across certain fields when passed to a function as an array. For example:

```
const src = [ { id:1, name: "name1", age: 25}, { id: 2, name: "name2", age: 33} ]
```

Say I want to search for only fields like `name` and `age` and not the id. Code that I tried

```
function contains(text, subStr) {
  return text.includes(subStr);
}

const searchInData = (searchString, searchData) => {
  const keyword = searchString.toLocaleLowerCase();
  let filteredData = searchData;
  if (keyword) {
    filteredData = searchData?.filter((item) => {
      const { name, age } = item;
      return (
        contains(name, keyword) ||
        contains(age, keyword) ||
      );
    });
  }
  return filteredData;
};
```

How can I pass in field names as array and only search for only those values. Something like,

```
searchInData(searchString, searchData, fieldsForSearch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the keys in the third argument and test for each key if the item's property with that key name includes the string. You can use `some` for that:

```js
function searchInData(searchString, searchData, fieldsForSearch) {
    const keyword = searchString.toLocaleLowerCase();
    // If no keys provided, search all of them
    if (!fieldsForSearch) {
        return searchData?.filter((item) =>
            Object.values(item).some(value => String(value).includes(keyword))
        );
    }
    // keys were provided: test those properties only
    return searchData?.filter((item) =>
        fieldsForSearch.some(field => Object.hasOwn(item, field) 
                                   && String(item[field]).includes(keyword))
    );
};

// demo
const src = [ { id:1, name: "name1", age: 25}, { id: 2, name: "name2", age: 33} ];

console.log(searchInData("name", src, ["id", "age"]).length); // 0
console.log(searchInData("3", src, ["id", "name"]).length); // 0
console.log(searchInData("3", src, ["age", "name"]).length); // 1
console.log(searchInData("2", src, ["age", "name"]).length); // 2
console.log(searchInData("u", src, ["nonexisting key"]).length); // 0
console.log(searchInData("1", src).length); // 1
```

Comment: I want to search across the objects, may be a function that takes in search string, search data and fields to be searched as three different parameters that returns entire matched object. I want to pass third argument as an array of fields

Comment: OK, I removed the spread syntax. So now third argument is array (optional argument). The snippet calls the function, but then only prints the length. Of course it returns an array of objects, but I didn't want to clutter the output

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that does what I think you want:

```js
const src = [ { id:1, name: "name1", age: 25}, { id: 2, name: "name2", age: 33} ]


function filterObjArr(fieldArr, src)
{
    const result = src.reduce((acc, cur) =>
    {
      fieldArr.forEach(field =>
      {
        if(cur[field])
        {
          acc.push({[field]: cur[field]});
        }
      });
      
      return acc;
    },[]);
    
    return result;
}

let res = filterObjArr(['name', 'age'], src);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I want to search across the objects, may be a function that takes in search string, search data and fields to be searched as three different parameters that returns entire matched object